# Chrome sync keeps on getting paused

Tags: windows, google-chrome, sync

For the past 3-6 months, Chrome has started to pause itself randomly. I can't tell whether this happens overnight or across reboots because it happens intermittently. I went through all the usual troubleshooting steps and even went as far as reinstalling Windows without copying over any files from my old installation. In spite of this, the bug remains.

Is there some sort of 2FA "feature" that is causing Chrome Sync to get paused on a regular basis to force users to re-authenticate with 2FA? Is this a known bug/feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked this down to a legitimate Windows bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1069383#c90

There is no fix at this time, but the workaround worked for me.